# Remove Element from std::vector<std::string> >

Tags: c++, linux, vector

My compiler complains.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

        vector<string> vec[2];
        vec[0].push_back("test1");
        vec[0].push_back("test2");

        cout << vec[0][0] << endl;
        vec[0].erase(vec.begin());
        cout << vec[0][1] << endl;

}
```

What is wrong when I call erase?

Comment: Please post the exact code you are trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vec` is an array of `vector<string>`s. I believe you meant `vec[0].begin()` like so:

```
vec[0].erase(vec[0].begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    vec[0].erase(vec[0].begin());
    cout << vec[0][1] << endl;
```

After you erased the first element, there's only one left. This one element is at position 0, which means index 1 is off bounds -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not undefined behaviour on vectors, out of range exception.

Comment: @Kernald: out-of-range would be thrown on `.at(1)` only.